# Django Error: No module named 'UserAuth.forms'

Tags: python, django, python-3.4, django-1.6

I have tried searching in the official *Django* documentation and few of the Stackoverflow questions.

However I do not get if my Form file is in the same directory as views.py file i.e `{{applicationfolder:UserAuth}}/` then why am I getting an error no module named `UserAuth.forms` found.

Can anyone please help me on this ?

Here is my code from my application:

```
#UserAuth/LoginForm.py
from django import forms
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Username/email',max_length=100)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,label='Password',max_length=16)

#UserAuth/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views import generic
from UserAuth.forms import LoginForm
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

# Create your views here.
class LoginView(FormView):
    form_class = LoginForm
    template_name = 'UserAuth/signin.html'

#When page loads for the first time
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Get Called")
        form = self.form_class(initial=self.initial)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

#When a post is called after the user submits the page.
    def post(self, request,*args, **kwargs):
        print ("Post called")
        context = RequestContext(request)
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        if Tooler:
            if Tooler.is_active:
                return HttpResponse("Logged in Successfully")
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Your account is disabled")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied.")


#UserAuth/templates/UserAuth/sigin.html
<form action="/login/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no module forms.
You need to understand what is a python module: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Changing the name of your LoginForm.py to forms.py should work.